# How to get http-server (npm package) to accept ES6 module syntax?

Tags: javascript, httpserver

Using something like python -m http.server, I have no problems with ES6 modules whatsoever. Likewise, if I want to execute my program in the terminal using the node command, ES6 modules don't work out of the box, but it's pretty simple to fix (by adding "type": "module",) to the top-level package.json. Is there a way to get http-server to accept ES6 syntax? I couldn't find info. about this anywhere. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use babel or something similar to compile the es6+ syntax to es5.

You can refer to [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-enable-es6-and-beyond-syntax-with-node-and-express-68d3e11fe1ab/) to find out more about this topic.